# Check if NSURLRequest target is "_blank"?

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm listening for url loads from my UIWebView. Is there a way to check if the request has a target of "_blank"?:

```
- (BOOL) webView:(UIWebView *)webView
         shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
         navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    if ([request targetIs:@"_blank"]) {
        // do something.
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think its possible to check if an `NSURLRequest` was from an `<a target="_blank">` link as they are created in response to many things such as Ajax requests, `iframe` loads, etc.
However, the effect you are wanting is similar to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8490038/931452).

Answer (score 1):

Don't know about iOS, but as for OS X, it works perfectly, if you use policy delegate. I've placed my answer in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46136134/7450481), mentioned by Russ above.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use [UIWebView -request] to get the NSURLRequest, and use [NSURLRequest URL] to check if the url contains anything you want.

Comment: Yes but a better approach for me would be to catch all urls with target="_blank" instead of having to define my own protocol to do the same.

Comment: I'm sorry but what do you mean by "defining my own protocol"?

Comment: For example, prefixing all my urls with something like "__pattern", or some other token so I know to act on these urls (instead of just relying on target="_blank").

Comment: So you mean the request is post by yourself, and you want UIWebView to do something special if the URL conforms to some specific pattern?

Comment: Yes I want to launch an instance of mobile safari with the given url if  target="_blank". This does not seem to work as it is.

Comment: Simply put, urls don't have a `target="_blank"` property or aspect about them, its an attribute of an anchor `<a>` HTML element. I honestly wish it was easy to see if the link tapped had this attribute as well