# Xcode WebView. Open target="_blank" links in Safari

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiwebview

I have a small app for **iOS** that uses **WebView**. I need links that contain **target = "_blank"** to open in Safari

I found a solution. But it does't work for me.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15048074/4489534

All links are now opened in Safari, and all links containing  **"?openInSafari = true"** too. But external(downloadable) files like **PDF** open in **WebView**.

I can't understand why the condition doesn't work

```
- (BOOL) webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest: (NSURLRequest *)request navigationType: (UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
        if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked) {
            NSURL *url = [request URL];
            NSString *string = [url query];

            if ([string rangeOfString: @"openInSafari=true"].location != NSNotFound){
                [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: url];
                NSLog(@"Open in Safari");
                return NO;
            }
        }
        NSLog(@"Open in WebView");
        return YES;

}
```

**EDITED**

When i click to link containing **"?openInSafari = true"**, i get **"Open in Safari openInSafari=true"**

When i click to normal link, i get **"Open in Safari (null)"**

When i click to downloadable link to PDF file, i get **"Open in WebView product_id=50&download_id=21"**

When i click to direct link to PDF file, i get **"Open in Safari (null)"**

Comment: Please share what string you are getting when pdf link is clicked.

Comment: if ([string rangeOfString: @"openInSafari=true"].location != NSNotFound) replace this code with this if (string.lenght>0)

Comment: It works. But this solution doesn't suit me. I have links like **index.php?route=account/address/add** and this links open in Safari

Comment: @SurbhiGarg I updated my question

Comment: so you need to put a separate condition for external links also, because they will have download_id

Comment: I found a solution for myself. I use **[string containsString: @"openInSafari=true"]** instead **[string rangeOfString: @"openInSafari=true"].location != NSNotFound**. It works great, but **containsString** сan be used only for **iOS 8** and later